# Assigning array to array by having pointer to its first element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is my function that in my belief (I am still trying to get used to pointers) returns a pointer to the first element of the array named `cords`:

```
int* getPosition( char arr[][5], char letter ) {
    int cords[2];
    for ( int y = 0; y < 5; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < 5; x++ ) {
            if ( arr[y][x] == letter ) {
                cords[0] = x;
                cords[1] = y;
            }
        }
    }
    return cords;
}
```

Here's my second function:

```
string scrambling( char arr[][5], vector<string> *pairs ) {
    string encrypted;
    int firstCords[2];
    ...
}
```

I want to somehow assign values from the array "cords" from the function `getPosition` to the array `firstCords` in the function `scrambling()`.

My temporary solution was:

```
firstCords[0] = getPosition( arr, (*pairs)[i][0] )[0];
firstCords[1] = getPosition( arr, (*pairs)[i][0] )[1];
```

And it's the only solution I came up with that actually works. I'm really keen on getting to know a way, how I can achieve this in one line ?

Comment: Well, let's start with the basics.  You cannot return cords in getPosition, as this is a local variable who's memory is not valid when the function returns.  If you want to return an array from that method, you have to allocate it (malloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cords` is a local variable, so using it beyond the end of the function it has been defined in is **undefined behavior**.

An easy way would be to pass a pointer to `firstCords` to `getPosition` and let `getPosition` fill it in. Declare `getPosition` like this:

```
void getPosition(int cords[2], char arr[][5], char letter);
```

And call it like that in `scrambling`:

```
getPosition(firstCords, arr, (*pairs)[i][0]);
```

**Note** that `int cords[2]` as a formal parameter to `getPosition` is not an array but a **pointer**.
[Here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428) is a nice (well, depends on how you define it) post on the Linux Kernel Mailing List by Linus Torvalds regarding some programmer who made a similar mistake.

Comment: Thanks :D !!! I forgot about that, it was only a local variable, but still it worked somehow... Anyway, your solution is great, it is exactly what I was looking for. :)